# Automatically add New Line(s) after 80th character in a string containing ANSI Escape Codes

Tags: go, terminal, extended-ascii

I want a Go program to display a CP437-encoded '[ANSI art file](https://16colo.rs/pack/mist0121/raw/LDA-PHASE90.ANS)', 80 columns wide, that contains [ANSI escape codes](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797) -- color, cursor placement, etc. and extended ANSI ([CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)) box drawing codes.

When viewing the ANSI file in a linux terminal (see Playground link below) with a 80 col CP437-capable terminal, the file displays properly, e.g. line breaks are implicitly read; **however**, when viewing with a wider terminal (which is the goal), new lines are not implicitly processed/added and the file may display improperly, without required line breaks.

How do I iterate through the .ans file and manually add new lines after the 80th character, counting only the actual characters displayed (not the escape codes)?

I've tried go libraries like [ansiwrap](https://github.com/manifoldco/ansiwrap) and [reflow](http://github.com/muesli/reflow/wrap). Ansiwrap is really just for text wrapping, but Reflow gets the closest to the goal, but the line breaks are not quite right.

[Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/_2e4SD0FUq6) of my test code with Reflow.

How it renders (in a CP437 terminal, 132x37):

[image: Viewed in Terminal application 132x37]

How it *should* look (from art program):

[image: reference image]

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant code and inputs. Links to 3rd party code-hosting platforms cannot form the only basis for reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, first I pulled `visualLength` function from the
`golang.org/x/term` package [1], then I wrote a `bufio.SplitFunc` [2] for this
use case.

```
package main

func ansi(data []byte, eof bool) (int, []byte, error) {
   var s []rune
   for i, r := range string(data) {
      if s = append(s, r); visualLength(s) == 80 {
         width := len(string(r))
         return i+width, data[:i+width], nil
      }
   }
   return 0, nil, nil
}
```

Result:

```
package main

import (
   "bufio"
   "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   f, err := os.Open("LDA-PHASE90.ANS")
   if err != nil {
      panic(err)
   }
   defer f.Close()
   s := bufio.NewScanner(charmap.CodePage437.NewDecoder().Reader(f))
   s.Split(ansi)
   for s.Scan() {
      println(s.Text())
   }
}
```

1. https://github.com/golang/term/blob/6886f2df/terminal.go#L431-L450
2. https://golang.org/pkg/bufio#SplitFunc